# Check two big objects for one property

Tags: c#

## Description

I´ve got a big object from a database by using a sqlite database with entity framework. Then I need to check if some entry´s from the database are not exist anymore by the new dataset I got from a import file. The objects have a length by ~120.000. The only I found was with the `where` and `any` extensions but this take minutes of time. Is there any solution that will be more efficent?

## Source

```
var delData = old.Where(o => !content.Data.Any(n => n.Row == o.Row));
```

## Class of the list

```
namespace GCS.Db
{
    public class GcsContent
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int HeadlineId { get; set; }
        public int TableId { get; set; }
        public int Row { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
}
```

## Example of htm list (content and old variables)

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content=''application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: What does your table structure look like? We're missing quite a bit of context here.

Comment: Write a SQL query that does the filtering on server side and return less objects right away? Use a WHERE ... statement or a JOIN ... ON ... statement.

Comment: The variables old and content have the same structure. old is from the database and the content is the new list of data from a htm file parsed. I could let the sqlite database check the data with a where clause but this would be ~800 request for the database. Is that clever?

Comment: Does your Row column have an index?

Comment: Yes all tables in my database has a auto increment id.

Comment: As you are selecting with the Row column the Row column should have an index. Your auto increment on the Id column does not matter here

Answer (score 0):

if understand correctly, you compare each element of old object to each element of new object. This causes exponential growth of combinations. Do you want to detect only deleted rows ? if yes, having identification of such rows (as id autoincrement) i think is not sufficient because you still need to iterate over whole collection to detect missing elements.

I would mark deleted rows with additional html tag so detection would require only one pass

Answer (score 0):

## First Solution

Cause the `Row` column isn´t unique I could use the `.distinct` to get fast the new row size of the htm. After that I can delete all other datasets which have a higher row then the new dataset with `RemoveRange`.

## Source

```
    var rows = content.Data.Select(x => x.Row).Distinct().Count() - 1;
    var delData = old.Where(x => x.Row > rows);
```

> I would mark deleted rows with additional html tag so detection would require only one pass

If you mean edit the htm it´s not possible cause it´s a auto generated table. I don´t have access to the source there.